# Weird query speed issue

Tags: mysql, performance, select, query-optimization

I have a table that has 2,707,047 rows total.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE status = 1 AND room_id IN (14, 16, 19, 21, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 39, 40, 45, 46, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 65, 66, 70, 71, 73, 76, 78, 84, 85, 86, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 101, 106, 113, 114, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 131, 134, 136, 138, 139, 140, 141, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 208, 209, 210, 212, 213, 214, 215, 217, 218) ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

takes 0.0059 secs

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE status = 1 AND room_id IN (40) ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

takes 0.0078 secs

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE status = 1 AND room_id IN (39) ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

takes 0.0510 secs

but why?

EXPLAIN for first query (multiple room_ids)
[image: explain for first query]

EXPLAIN for second query (room_id 39)
[image: room_id 39]

EXPLAIN for third query (room_id 40)
[image: room_id 40]

Answer (score 2):

The optimal index for your second and third queries is:  `messages(status, room_id, post_date)`.  With this index, I would expect the performance to be pretty much the same.

Without the index, the query is getting rows that match the `where` clause and then sorting them.  Well, if room 39 has many more matching rows than room 40, then it will take longer to sort.

You haven't included other useful information in your question . . . such as the "explain" plan for the queries or the existing indexes.  But, there are good reasons why changing the value from 39 to 40 would affect the results.

EDIT:

The first is fast because of happenstance.  Because of the `in` condition, MySQL decides that the index on `status, room_id, post_date` is not optimal.  Instead, it reads the index for the dates in descending order, and it happens to find a row that matches the `where` conditions very quickly.

The second and third performance differences are a bit mysterious.  They suggest that MySQL is doing an index scan to get to the last post date in the matching part of the index.  However, I wouldn't expect a factor of 7 in performance, given that the data is not that large.

Are these performance characteristics consistent?  Do the difference hold in a cold-cache environment?

Comment: room_id 39 has 6,070 rows while room_id 40 has 11,936. That's why I call it weird. The one with less rows is somehow slower.

Comment: @Wellenbrecher . . . It also depends on where those rows are located in the table.  The proposed index should work consistently.

Comment: @Wellenbrecher . . . Edit your question and add the `explain` for the three queries.

Comment: I've added "explain"s for each query.

Comment: @Wellenbrecher -- the timing diff could be related to caching.  Another way to investigate: `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `LIMIT 0, 1`, the longer `IN` clause is generally going to evaluate faster (without an index), because it can stop as soon as it finds *any* of the `room_id`s, whereas the other two queries must find the *exact* `room_id` specified.

I think the different between the second and third query probably just depends on where in the scan the specific `room_id` occurs.

Comment: But there's also an "order by". I think it won't stop as soon as it finds any of the room_ids. It should scan all room_ids in order to find the row with highest post_date

Comment: @Wellenbrecher . . . I'm pretty sure it will either take the extreme value from the index *or* sort the data and take the first row.  I don't think MySQL will scan just for the extreme value.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says `Key=post_date`.  Now, guessing that that refers to `INDEX(post_date)`, here is what is happening:  It is walking through that index starting at the end.  As it walks through, it is checking `status` and `room_id`.  Apparently (based on the fast time), it quickly found a row with `status=1` and `room_id` equal to one of those.  The `EXPLAIN` did not mention any sort; none should be needed.  **Risk**:  If it has to scan a million rows before finding a desired status&room_id, the query will be slow.